# Block direct link of an image but keep displaying it in pages

Tags: image, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Lets say I'm using Apache and I have a sample web folder like:

> http://myserver.com/test/

In this folder I have the following files:

- index.html
- img.php
- sample.jpg
- .htaccess

The `index.html` have the following code:

```
<html>
    <body>
         <img src="sample.jpg" />
    </body>
</html>
```

The `img.php` have the following code:

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_GET["path"])){
       exit()
    }
?>
<html>
    <body>
         <img src="<?php echo $_GET["path"] ?>" />
    </body>
</html>
```

**I like http://myserver.com/test/sample.jpg to show http://myserver.com/test/img.php?path=sample.jpg content**
(with no URL change)

After a lot of search on the net I wrote the following code but it does not work :/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(png|gif|jpe?g)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} \.(php|html)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /test/img.php?path=$1 [L]
```

There is probably an `!` to put on the third line but I do not know exactly where

Comment: Don't you end up with the same request out of the PHP as the original HTML?

Comment: On this exemple yes. But on my project the PHP and the HTML end up different.

Comment: How many pictures are we talking about on a page? If its not too many you could always have php read the image data and echo the base64 code, cant exactly link to that :)

Comment: About 20 pics. It ca be a solution...

Comment: How would you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your .htaccess code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/

# block direct access to images
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?myserver\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?\.(?:png|gif|jpe?g))$ img.php?path=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: thank but it does not work: the URL change to `http://myserver.com/test/img.php?path=sample.jpg` and the image is broken in both of index.html and img.php because they do not have the correct source path.

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted when you wrote: `http://myserver.com/test/img.php?path=sample.jpg` ? I have remove R flag now so it won't change the URL but still you will 404 if your img.php doesn't serve the right image.

Comment: Thank. Here is the trick: apply the PHP if the user enter the direct link in his browser, else do nothing so pages (`img.php`,`index.html`,etc...) can keep showing this image.
I guess there is a RewriteCond to put somewhere.

Comment: If I understand you right I believe you need check based on HTTP_REFERER. Edited the code, pls check it.

Comment: Almost, it works only for the first pic when there is more than one. I have no idea why :/

Comment: Theoretically it should work for all the images in a page. `%{HTTP_REFERER}` cannot change all of a sudden between 2 images.

Comment: Here is the `img.php`: http://jmercadier.fr/maman/img.php?path=art/dessins/1.JPG and here is some pics: 
http://jmercadier.fr/maman/art/dessins/1.JPG , http://jmercadier.fr/maman/art/portraits/brunehilde.jpg , http://jmercadier.fr/maman/art/portraits/Numeriser1.jpg

Answer (score 1):

To output an image as base64, you would use something like this:

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode(file_get_contents('/path/to/image.jpg'));?>"/>
```

Remember that's server path, not document root, so you may need to add `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` in front of your normal image file path